# Error in p-limit lib when importing @google-cloud/storage to deploy firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, function

I am trying to deploy a firebase function with the command firebase deploy, but when I import @google-cloud/storage

```
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
```

I get this error

```
Detailed stack trace: /srv/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:30
            } catch {}
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/srv/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js:25:16)
```

The problem is that I found this error in p-limit/index.js in the following code

```
    const run = async (fn, resolve, ...args) => {
    activeCount++;

    // TODO: Get rid of `pTry`. It's not needed anymore.
    const result = pTry(fn, ...args);

    resolve(result);

    try {
        await result;
    } catch {}

    next();
};
```

But if I edit this part of the code and deploy again, I get the same error, so it seems that it's not reading this file.. it's getting this error in some other place that I cant find..

Someone can help?

Comment: Having the same issue here. What is weird is the commit that changed that line in p-limit is around 16 days ago but we only started having the problem 2 days ago.
I left a comment for the developer about it hoping he will fix it:
https://github.com/sindresorhus/p-limit/commit/b35faf54fb0871d9ae592069a18083a2ba15d8a9

Comment: try NVM use node(version), the version of you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of node are you running? I had the same exact same message when I tried using it today and has been driving me crazy. I was using Node 8.12. Try upgrading to the latest version of node 12.18.1. It resolved that error for me.

Comment: You are right! I changed the node version to 10 (the last) inside package.json in the function folder, so it deployed in node 10 inside the cloud, instead version 8... so it worked
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error with a node app (not firebase related though). Looks `@google-cloud/storage` starting from its version 5.0 [dropped support](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/issues/1223) for Node 8.

One option is to upgrade to Node versions >=10. My project though required to use Node 8. So another option is to use `@google-cloud/storage` prior to 5.0. For example, this worked for me in `package.json` with Node 8

```
...
"@google-cloud/storage": "5.0.0",
...
```